# Print the number -99'999'999'999'999.99

Tags: c++

I want to print the number -99'999'999'999'999.99, and not an approximation of that number. How can I do it?

Here is my Code:

```
        double number = - 99'999'999'999'999.99;

        std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(20) << "Number: " << number << std::endl;
```

and the Output:

Number: -99999999999999.98437500000000000000

Please help me with a solution to print and do some calculations with the exact same number.

Comment: floating point types are a lossy data type.  The range they can represent requires more bits than the storage has so some values will not be able to be exactly representable.

Comment: This number _cannot be stored exactly_ in floating-point types like `float` or `long double`. Literally impossible. In any language that uses IEEE-754-based floating-point numbers. If you need that level of precision, either count in cents and integer types (like `int64_t`) or use arbitrary-precision arithmetic like Boost.Multiprecision.

Comment: I want to be able to manipulate the number, it's my only requirement.

Comment: you can manipulate a string, and you can print it without loosing digits. `std::string number{"- 99'999'999'999'999.99"};`

Comment: You can use a *binary coded decimal* (**BCD**, either packed or unpacked).  The standard C++ library has no support for BCD, but there are third party libraries for C++ available that support BCD. Or you could write your own BCD, it is not very hard.  (Or use a **fixed** point number.  The number provided would fit in a fixed point number that used a std::int64_t as backing store.)

Comment: `_Decimal128` ?

Comment: What do you mean by "manipulate"? You would be better off using a language that supports BCD arithmetic if exact decimal fractions are a strict requirement for you (or working on a machine that uses radix-10 FP arithmetic and enough bits). Are there **any** radix-10 floating point hardware machines in production today? If you describe what you want to do to this number it might be possible to suggest a way forward. String representation is easy if you just want to print it out exactly.

Comment: I also want to be able to do some calculations with it.

Comment: If these are simple additions and subtractions you could still use a std::string and bit of grade school math or you could use a big math library or you could use a BCD library or you could compute as cents using a 64 bit integer

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the world of floating point numbers.  As @NathanOliver and @yeputons remarked, a double cannot represent all possible values.  On my machine (x86_64), your number has the representation `-0x1.6bcc41e8fffffp+46`.  The next possible value is `-0x1.6bcc41e900000p+46;`, which has the value `-100000000000000`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    double number = - 99'999'999'999'999.99;

    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(20) << 
                                         "Number: " << number << std::endl;
                                         
    std::cout << std::hexfloat << number << std::endl;
    
    double number2 = -0x1.6bcc41e8fffffp+46;
    double number3 = -0x1.6bcc41e900000p+46;
    std::cout << std::hexfloat << number2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::hexfloat << number3 << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(20) << 
                                         "Number3: " << number3 << std::endl;
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reason your way through this.

- A single precision number has 23 bits in the mantissa, and 2^23=8 times 10^6, so it can represent a number to approx 7 significant digits.
- A double precision number has 51 bits in the mantissa, and 2^51=2 times 10^15, so it can represent a number to approx 15 significant digits.

How many digits does your number have? Maybe your C++ installation has a quad precision type?

PS the above depends a little on what your definition of "=" is, to paraphrase a former president.

Comment: It has 14 before the comma and 2 after it. A total of 16 digits

Comment: Which means you can't use double if your requirement is to retain accuracy in 16 digits.

Comment: what options do I have?

Comment: You were given several options already as comments to the question.